# How to check how and when a user checked their Exchange 2010 mailbox?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email

We are trying to obtain the IP addresses and protocols (e.g., POP3, IMAP or MAPI) that a specific user had been using to connect to her mailbox.

How would we go about obtaining data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick google search found [Setting Network Connection Logging for Exchange Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195916)

> 1. Start the Exchange Server Administrator program, click
>      Configuration, click Servers, click
>      the , and then click
>      Directory Service.
> 2. Click on the Diagnostic Logging tab, and set the Logging level for
>      MAPI Interface to "Maximum".

Comment: Thanks for the typo correction!

I'm assuming this means that, if the setting was not set, then I'm S.O.L..

Comment: For the past, then yeah.